# Arduino 9 DOF sensor SDA/SCL (LSM303, L3GD20) hangs at start

Tags: arduino, sensor

I'm having an issue with my (Adafruit opensource knockoff) Arduino 9 DOF sensor.

It hangs at start, when calling the begin-functions.

I'm running it on an Arduino Nano (5v version).

I have tried to run the sensor from 3.3v source and the 5v source connected to VIN on the sensor.

I have swapped out both the Arduino Nano and the sensor, but the issue persists.

Skipping the begin functions doesn't work either; I'll get 0-results.

The sensors are Chinese clones. I wouldn't be surprised if one was broken, but I find it odd that both would be.

I'm followed the tutorial from the Adafruit page and implemented the tester.pde from the 9 DOF github.

**Edit:**
I'm going to try tomorrow to change the wires. I've been burnt before because of faulty breadboard wires.

**Edit:**
No luck with switching wires. I'm beginning to believe these boards are cursed and I should switch them to another brand.

Comment: Do you have a schematic? Are all relevant pins strapped to a known state on power on? PUs on SDA/SCL obviously, but any other pins that float?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was the library that was at fault. I switched from the Adafruit one to:

https://github.com/pololu/l3g-arduino/

https://github.com/pololu/lsm303-arduino

and now I get actual values that seem to be in an expected range.

Comment: The question doesn't mention neither which hardware the OP has, nor which libraries whey are using. What makes you think their problem is similar to yours?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm OP. Apparently I logged in to the wrong account, or something else is going wrong. I don't recall every making an account called DariusJoe..

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Also there's only 1 Adafruit 9 DOF sensor AFAIK, and I even put the chipset in the title.